# Selecting Radio Buttons based on User Input in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to select a radio button based on User input. This radio button has multiple options with the same name.

```html
<th class="radio">
 <td>
  <label for="form-1-input-3">
   <input id="form-1-input-3" type="radio" checked="" value="true" name="enabled">
   Enabled  
  </label>
  <label for="form-1-input-4">
   <input id="form-1-input-4" type="radio" value="false" name="enabled">
   Disabled  
  </label>
```

If "enabled" is passed as a string, I should be able to select the first radio button that has the visible text, Enabled and if "disabled" is passed as a string, I should be able to select radio button that has visible text, Disabled.

I am having difficulty since the name of the radio button is same. The below code fails to find the element with the AND operator for Xpath. Has anyone encountered this before and have found a solution?

```java
String enableRadioButtonXPath = "//input[contains(@id,'form-') and contains(@value, 'enabled')]";
String enableRadioButtonOption = "enabled";
String disableRadioButtonOption = "disabled";

WebElement enableRadioButton = webdriver1.findElement(By.name(enableRadioButtonOption));
enableRadioButton.click();
```

Comment: The `id` value of the two radio buttons are different then why can't you go for Id. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: id's for radio buttons are dynamically generated, so cannot locate by id

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This logic might be useful for you.

For selecting first radio button use below locator

```java
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Enable')]/input")).click();
```

For selecting second radio button which has disable text

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Disable')]/input")).click();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help:

```java
public void selectByName (final WebDriver driver, final String status) {
    final List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("enabled"));

    for (WebElement radio : radios) {
        if (radio.getText().equals(status)) {
            radio.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the user input and assign to a variable called `Usrinput`

```
List<WebElement> radiobuttons = driver.findElements(By.name("radiobuttonname"));
    for(WebElement radiobutton: radiobuttons) { 

    if(radiobutton.getAttribute("value").equals("Usrinput"))
        radiobutton.click();
}
```